# smart-table : Conditional st-sort

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Is there any way to have conditional st-sort in smart-table. Example - I have an array which tells me the columns in my table which are sortable. Lets say my table has columns [FirstName, LastName, Age, email] and my sorters array is [firstName, age], which means only firstname and age fields are sortabe. How can I achieve this using smart-talbe. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: posted my code below!

Answer (score 0):

The way smart table wants you to specify if a column is sortable or not is by using the `st-sort` directive in your `<thead>`, it tells which column should be sortable by what object property, like so:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th> <!-- sortable rows -->
    <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
    <th st-sort="age">age</th>
    <th>email</th> <!-- not sortable -->
</tr>
</thead>
```

what you're saying is that you have an array that tells your table which column is sortable and which is not.
In my opinion is a very awkward way to do things in general and it can't really be done neatly in ST.

You can however write a directive that conditionally adds or removes `st-sort` from your table using values from an array. but that will just be a mess

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is an awkward way to do but that's how the services are returning data to us. I tried the following code and got it working(It sorts the firstname and age columns. ), although it doesn't seem a very clean approach to me -

In my HTML -

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-ratio="20" ng-attr-st-sort="sorters.getSorter('firstName')">first name</th> <!-- sortable rows -->
            <th st-ratio="20" ng-attr-st-sort="sorters.getSorter('lastName')">last name</th>
    <th st-ratio="10" ng-attr-st-sort="sorters.getSorter('age')">age</th>
    <th st-ratio="30" ng-attr-st-sort="sorters.getSorter('email')">email</th>
    <th st-ratio="20" ng-attr-st-sort="sorters.getSorter('balance')">balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

`enter code here`

In my js -

```
 $scope.sorters = {
                getSorter: function(prop){
                  return function(value){
                    var sortables = ['firstName', 'age'];
                    for(var i=0;i<sortables.length; i++){
                      if(sortables[i] === prop) {
                        return value[prop];
                      };
                    }

                    return undefined;
                  }
                }
              };
```

Although this solves my problem, I dont like the approach. Is there any better option to this? 
P.S - I will eventually be converting this to a directive if I have no better option.